# boolean does not change its value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck with this code and do not understand why it's not working as I expect. This way, the boolean variable "x" changes its value every time I click the `#btn`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = false;
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    toggleBtn(x);
    x = !x;
  });
  function toggleBtn(x) {
    if (!x) {
      doThis();
    } else {
      doThat();
    }
  };
});
```

But this way, "x" does not change it's value:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = false;
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    toggleBtn(x);
  });
  function toggleBtn(x) {
    if (!x) {
      doThis();
    } else {
      doThat();
    }
    x = !x;
  };
});
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you have *two* `x` variables.

One is declared here:

```
var x = false;
```

The other is declared here:

```
function toggleBtn(x) {
```

In the first example, you're updating the value of the first `x`.  In the second example, you're updating the value of the *second* `x`.  Which then immediately falls out of scope when the function ends and is destroyed.

Comment: Can I update the value of the first x from the function toggleBtn(x) {}?

Comment: @brigysl: I suspect you can just remove the `x` parameter from the function entirely at that point, that way all references will use the higher-scoped `x`.

Comment: but what if I have var x,var y, and var z for three different buttons that run the same toggleBtn(x) {}?

Answer (score 2):

Try it :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     var x = false;

    $("#btn").click(function() {
        toggleBtn(x);
    })

    function toggleBtn(x) {
        if (!x)
            doThis();

        else 
            doThat();         
    }

    function doThis() {
        alert("do This");
        x = !x;
    }

    function doThat() {
        alert("do That");
        x = !x;
    }

})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn">OK</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        
$(document).ready(function(){
    
     var x = false;
    
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        
        toggleBtn(x);
        
    })
    
    function toggleBtn(x) {
        
        if (!x)
            doThis();
        
        else 
            doThat();
                
    }
    
    function doThis() {
        alert("do This");
        x = !x;
    }
    
    function doThat() {
        alert("do That");
        x = !x;
    }
})
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works fine if I have only one button. But what if I have multiple buttons doing the same function?

Comment: @brigysl ,  you can use of `class` for multiple buttons or `id` for one button.